# Issues in dimensions and slicing while plotting contours over a FITS Image in Astronomical Plotting Library in python (APLpy)

Tags: python, image-processing, fits

I have been trying to plot the contours of a FITS image over itself in [APLpy](https://aplpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/). The image was created in AIPS, and has dimensions (1024,1024,1,1), viz., right ascension (RA--SIN), declination (DEC--SIN), frequency (FREQ), and Stokes (STOKES). I tried to load the FITS image and plot the contours of this image over itself, using the following commands -

```
baseimg = aplpy.FITSFigure('FILENAME.FITS') 
baseimg.show_contour('FILENAME.FITS')
```

This returned the error `WCS has more than 2 pixel dimensions, so 'slices' should be set`.

So, I specified the dimensions and slices while loading the FITS image, as-

```
baseimg = aplpy.FITSFigure('FILENAME.FITS', dimensions=[0,1],slices=[0,0])
```

i.e., specifying RA and DEC as the x and y axes respectively, and using the only available value of Frequency and Stokes as the slice. Trying to plot contour again as-

```
baseimg.show_contour('FILENAME.FITS')
```

or

```
baseimg.show_contour('FILENAME.FITS', dimensions=[0,1],slices=[0,0])
```

again gives the same error `WCS has more than 2 pixel dimensions, so 'slices' should be set`.

I am stumped as to what I am doing wrong here. I am absolutely new to APLpy. Any help is immensely appreciated.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is discussing coding in python, which is better suited on StackOverflow

Comment: @harada This is not a question of coding in python in general. APLpy (the Astronomical Plotting Library in Python - pronounced apple pie) is a Python package module aimed at producing publication-quality plots of astronomical imaging data. I therefore put it here. This forum has several well received questions of astropy too. If you want to migrate it to SO, alright, I would trust your judgement and hope SO could answer such a specific question. But I am against closing this.

Comment: **on-topic!**  @harada consider that question includes the site's [python tag](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/python?tab=Votes) which can be found on 84 previous questions, and that "better suited" is not a close reason. As long as a question is not off-topic, OP decides where to post. Python is a tool many (most?) Astronomers use daily to learn about the universe.

Comment: @uhoh Okay cool. I've retracted my close vote. Your explanation + the post edits make the intentions of the post more clear, and I agree it should stay open. Sorry for any confusion.

Comment: Thank you @harada. I realise my original post could have been misleading, hence the edits. Thank you very much for the bounty as well!